# Web API: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-web-api, routes

So I have one endpoint on my ASP.NET Web API project that needs to accept special characters (such as `%`, `<`, `>`) to validate the uniqueness of a name within the system. So for the following route:

```
[Route("~/api/case/{name}/infosys/{system}")]
```

... `{name}` may contain a special character. For **this endpoint only** is there a way that I can tell Web API to allow special characters and not give this error:

```
HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%).
```

**Note:** This is a Web API project so the `[ValidateInput(false)]` and `[AllowHtmlAttribute]` decorators are not available. Also, I don't want to loosen this restriction on any other endpoint by modifying my Web.config:

```
No
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />

...

No
<pages validateRequest="false">

...

No
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
```

Comment: AllowHtmlAttribute maybe?

Comment: @JamesR. Well, I'm not necessarily allowing just HTML for this route, and `AllowHtmlAttribute` is not available in Web API.

Comment: oh well. Sorry, was just taking a shot in the dark...

Comment: @OliverSpryn: Did you find a solution meeting your requirements?  I too do not want to update web.config and want to have action (or controller) specific. Could you please tell me how you solved this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I tested this piece of code and it works:

```
httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,\,?"
```